# editing a list of lists python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have the following code

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self, size=7):
        self._size = size
        self._list, self._llist =[],[]
        for i in range (self._size):
            self._list.append('_ ')
        for j in range(self._size):
            self._llist.append(self._list)
    def printboard(self):
        for i in range(self._size):
            for j in range(self._size):
                print(self._llist[i][j], end = ' ')
            print('\n')

    def updateboard(self,x,y,letter):
        self._llist[x][y]=letter
        self.printboard()

board = Board(3)
board.updateboard(0,0,'c')
```

and this prints

```
c _  _ 

c _  _  

c _  _
```

instead of

```
c _  _ 

_ _  _  

_ _  _
```

I can't see what is going wrong. Also, is there a simpler way to create the list of lists dynamically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `llist` with the same `list` object, repeated multiple times.  If you want each list in `llist` to be a separate, independent object (so that when you modify the contents only one list is changed) then you need to append a different copy to each.  The easiest way to do this is to change:

```
self._llist.append(self._list)
```

to

```
self._llist.append(list(self._list))
```

Simpler code would be:

```
self._list = ['_ '] * self._size
self._llist = [list(self._list) for i in range(self._size)]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. But I dont understand why the list is changing when I change only one field in llsit?

Comment: what you were doing was making three labels all pointing to the same list.  what i did was make three different lists.  read that page through a couple of times and hopefully you'll get the idea.  note - on that page they do self._list[:] which is another way of doing what i did with list(self._list).  also, stop calling variables "list" because it is confusing! :o)